# admob with uiwebview iOS

Tags: ios, webview, admob

I have a problem with the admob ad covering my webView content. I´ve understood there´s something that can be done with making webview and bannerview siblings, but I have an In-app purchase from which the user can remove the ads. Does anyone have any idea how to make the bannerview appear above the webView and if the user buys the in-app purchase, I want the webview to cover the entire screen again.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can have the `bannerView` and `UIWebView` be sibling views. If a user completes the purchase, you can programmatically remove the `bannerView` from your Window.